# Squid Transparent Port Redirection

Tags: port-forwarding, squid

I'm running Squid 5.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. I set this machine up as a web filter for my children. The proxy functions appear to work fine. I am pretty sure at least one of the children will be able to figure out how to remove the proxy settings on the computer, so I was going to route the traffic through the server and have Squid filter it that way.

I set up packet forwarding and traffic flows through just fine. I'm able to view test webpages etc. However, when I modify my PREROUTING statements to redirect port 80 traffic to 3128, I receive an error in the web browser stating "Invalid URL".

[image]

My Squid config is as follows:

```
access_log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log
acl localnet src 192.168.1.0/24
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump bump all
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
error_directory /usr/local/squid/share/errors
acl me src 192.168.1.33
acl kids src 192.168.1.215 192.168.1.253
acl ksm dstdomain "/usr/local/squid/etc/kidssocialmedia.txt
acl chat dstdomain "/usr/local/squid/etc/chatdomains.txt"
acl porn dstdomain "/usr/local/squid/etc/porndomains.txt"
acl webmail dstdomain "/usr/local/squid/etc/webmaildomains.txt"
deny_info ERR_TROLL_KIDS kids ksm
http_reply_access deny kids ksm
http_access deny kids ksm
deny_info ERR_TROLL_PORN kids porn
http_reply_access deny kids porn
http_access deny kids porn
deny_info ERR_TROLL_WEBMAIL kids webmail
http_reply_access deny kids webmail
http_access deny kids webmail
deny_info ERR_TROLL_CHAT kids chat
http_reply_access deny kids chat
http_access deny kids chat
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_port 3128 ssl-bump cert=/usr/local/squid/etc/ssl_cert/myCA.pem generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB
sslcrtd_program /usr/local/squid/libexec/security_file_certgen -s /usr/local/squid/var/logs/ssl_db -M 4MB
coredump_dir /usr/local/squid/var/cache/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern \/(Packages|Sources)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/Release(|\.gpg)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/InRelease$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/(Translation-.*)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
cache_dir ufs /mount/storage/squid 4096 16 256
maximum_object_size_in_memory 0
maximum_object_size 250
cache_mem 0
```

This is what I have in my UFW rules.before file before the filter section:

> *nat :PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
>
> -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
>
> COMMIT

The server's main interface is br0 (192.168.1.149). Without the redirect statement in place, traffic routes through the server to the internet gateway (192.168.1.1) with no issue. And setting web browser proxy settings to 192.168.1.149:3128 works with no issue.

I tried DNAT statements as well, and that did not work either. I do not like the idea of using DNAT anyway, if possible, as I do not want to masquerade traffic as the squid server. I also have another machine that I can use for port redirection if that is preferred.